# Need to turn off e.preventDefault(); for a specific menu link

Tags: jquery

I have a page with scrolling and am using the following to assist the scrolling of my page, everything is great but the e.preventDefault(); bit has deactivated one of the menu items that needs to function as a normal hyperlink, not a scrolling initiating link. How do I target it specifically and turn off the e.preventDefault(); affect?  I have seen a few similar problems mentioned here on this forum but nothing that made sense to me or helped my situation. Any assistance hugely appreciated with this.

This is Easing Effects code:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {           
    e.preventDefault();
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top-  offsetTop }, 2500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    history.pushState({}, "", this.href);           
});
```

This is menu that's being affected. The News link is the one I need to behave normally and have added a class to it to target it.

```
<ul id="nav" class="nav">
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#why">Why Us</a></li>                
    <li><a class="allowLinkToWork" href="news.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried things like the following which I thought would work:
    $('.nav a.allowLinkToWork[href^="http"]').unbind('click', handler);

Comment: `if($(this).is(".allowLinkToWork"))return;`.

Comment: Instead of using an `if` condition, its better if you don't bind the `click` event on the menu item

Comment: Not sure why @haim770 has deleted his answer: `$('.nav').on('click', 'a:not(.allowLinkToWork)', function(e) {...});`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it hasn't worked, I may have got something wrong, but the answer below from Rory McCrossn has worked so I'll leave it there for now. Cheers for looking into it anyway!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `hasClass()` to identify the element that you want to allow the click through, and then not apply the `preventDefault()`. Try this:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {           
    if (!$(this).hasClass('allowLinkToWork'))
        e.preventDefault();

    // your code...     
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You could test for menu item class name to detect it and avoid `preventDefault`

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {           
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.hasClass('allowLinkToWork')) {
         e.preventDefault();    
    }
    href = $this.attr('href');
    $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top-  offsetTop }, 2500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    history.pushState({}, "", this.href);           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the whole function you need to deactivate, follow @haim770 answer

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'a:not(.allowLinkToWork)', function(e) {
    ...
};
```

If you need to deactivate only the `e.preventDefault()` bit do the following:

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'a', function(e) {           
    if (!$(this).hasClass('allowLinkToWork')) { // changed
        e.preventDefault();
    } // changed
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(href).offset().top-offsetTop }, 2500, 'easeInOutExpo');
    history.pushState({}, "", this.href);           
});
```

Comment: I edited because an element could have more than just one class (even this is not the case in OP posted HTML markup)

Answer (score 0):

Shortest solution is just don't bind any event on required link ,replace here

```
$('.nav').on('click', 'a:not(.allowLinkToWork)', function(e)
```